# How can I execute my Thomas Algorithm function using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have created a function to execute the thomas algorithm. I'm trying to use my function to solve a system with the following arrays:

b = -4ε + 2αh^2

a = 2ε - h(1+α(n+1)h)

c = 2ε + h(1+αnh)

g = 4kπh^2sin(kπnh)

where α=1.2, k=2, ε=0.02, R=4

I've inserted my function (below), but I'm not completely sure how to enter in these parameters in the command window as I'm pretty new to Matlab. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function y = ThomasAlgorithm(a,b,c,f)
   % obtain values
   m = length(f);
     f(1) = f(1)/b(1);
     % Forward Substitution
     for j = 1:m-1
         c(j) = c(j)/b(j);
         b(j+1) = b(j+1) - a(j)*c(j);
         f(j+1) = (f(j+1) - a(j)*f(j))/b(j+1);
     end;
     % Backwards Substitution
     for k = m-1:-1:1
         f(k) = f(k) - c(k)*f(k+1);
     end;
     % Output
     y = f;
  end
```

I tried to put this into the command window (below) but I got the error:

```
Error in ThomasAlgorithm (line 11)
       b(j+1) = b(j+1) - a(j)*c(j);
```

I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong at the moment or how to solve it and I've kind of hit a wall.

```
>> m=10;
x0=0, xm=1;
y0=R, ym=0;
alpha=1.2;
k=2;
eps=0.02;
R=4;
h=xm-x0/m;
a=[2*eps-h*(1+alpha*((1:m-1)+1)*h)];
b=[-4*eps+2*alpha*h*h];
c=[2*eps+h*(1+(alpha*(1:m-1)*h))];
f=[4*k*pi*h*h*sin(k*pi*(1:m-1)*h)];
x=ThomasAlgorithm(a,b,c,f);
for ic=1:n
disp(x);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the stuff you've put in the command window into a separate [**script**](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/scripts.html) (`.m` file) instead, then run it. This allows you to get the actual full error message, and keeps the command window clutter free!

When running the *script* with your code in, you see the following error:

> **Undefined function or variable 'R'.**
>   Error in myScript (line 3)
>   y0=R, ym=0;

**Now your (first) problem is clear! You set `y0=R` when `R` doesn't exist.**
It's good practise at times like this to run `clear` before you run your script, so your workspace is emptied and you know what you've not defined in the script.

So we add `R = 1` or something to the start, then run it again. **Now we have an indexing error**!

> **Index exceeds matrix dimensions.**
>   Error in ThomasAlgorithm (line 8)
>   b(j+1) = b(j+1) - a(j)*c(j);

This is because you defined `b` as

```
b=[-4*eps+2*alpha*h*h]; % a SCALAR not a vector!
```

Then passed it to `ThomasAlgorithm` and expected to be able to index it, when it isn't a vector.

---

Hopefully that points out the immediate problem, and how to better diagnose issues. Also when your code is in a script you can [step through it](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) to debug things.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the b=[-4*eps+2*alpha*h*h]; issue, but I'm not really sure how to turn it into an array

Comment: I have no idea what `b` is meant to represent... should it be a constant array the same size as `a`?

Comment: b is an array, but it is the main diagonal in a tridiagonal matrix, with a and c being the sub and super diagonal arrays

Comment: In your original definitions of a, b and c, what do you think makes them arrays? Clarify in your head (then here) how to define those things mathematically, then you can define them in code!

Comment: I multipled b by (1:m-1) to turn it into a vector. So b = [(1:m-1)*-4*eps+2*alpha*h*h];

Comment: I think you maybe need to multiple by (1:m), otherwise you will be indexing out of range when `j=m`. I think maybe this applies to your other vectors too. Remember the `m` in your script is different to the `m` in your function!